# How to handle questions that ask for tutorials specific to a subject?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was reviewing the first post queue and had to review a question that approximately asked:

> I've learned subject *X* in class, so in theory, I know how it should happen.
>
> But how can I do it in *language Z*? Are there any tutorial out there?

*language Z* could be replaced by *framework Z*.

I never know if these should be flagged/closed as *Too Broad* or *Off-Topic > How to get started*, or even if they should be left alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions asking for tutorials are too broad; we don't provide *lists of* resources.

However, there's a pretty good chance that a question asking for tutorial for an appropriately-scoped concept could simply be edited to ask how to accomplish the task itself.

Comment: Then if the question about _Subject X_ has already plenty of questions (and answers) which explain how to do it, it should just probably be closed as duplicate..?

Comment: If you could edit the question such that it *wasn't* a duplicate, that would be ideal. But if the only way to edit it is to make it a duplicate, that's an option as well. Or you could just not edit it and flag it for closure.

Comment: Ah, right, that should be considered as well!

Comment: There wasn't a post here in meta which showed sites for forums that they could ask that? Maybe it would be the case to put that somewhere easier to find. Kinda off-topic, I know

Comment: @DH., the Help Center already has that list at the bottom of [this page](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).